# Scout SDK: Online address search for android app

Tags: android, skmaps

Using ScoutSDK I am writing application for offline navigation.
I have ~200mb prepackaged maps and I successfully implemented offline address search with the help of `SKMultiStepSearchSettings`.

As refer application I am using "GPS Navigation & Maps - Scout" from Google Play Store (they are using Scout SDK also). So in this application I saw, that they require to have cached map in order to search for addresses in offline mode. But if you are in online mode - the application perform address search without cached map. The result for same criteria is different in online/offline mode.

So the question is - how should I approach in order to use online address search for Scout SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When used offline the "GPS Navigation & Maps - Scout" defaults to OSM only multi-step search (the same functionality you also have access to).

When online, the app integrates also external (licensed) data for search purposes - this is something done at app level and cannot be exposed via the SDK (as it's  a licensed, commercial service).

You have the ability to do the same thing in your app - when used online, integrate an external 3'rd party geocoding service.